# SQLite full text search indexes

Tags: sqlite, fts3

I currently have a diagnosis table.  I want to make the code and description fields searchable using FTS.  As I understand it though, FTS tables don't support indexes and I need to be able to lookup Diagnosis by diagnosisID very quickly.  Am I going to have to create a second virtual table with all of the data duplicated just for full text searching or am I missing a solution where I dont have to duplicate all of my diagnosis codes and descriptions?

```
CREATE TABLE Diagnosis (  
    diagnosisID     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,  
    code            TEXT,  
    collect         INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    description     TEXT  
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out an FTS table has a hidden `rowid` field, which you can populate when you are entering data:

```
sqlite> create virtual table test1 using fts3;
sqlite> insert into test1 values ("This is a document!");
sqlite> insert into test1(docid,content) values (5,"this is another document");
sqlite> select rowid,* from test1;
1|This is a document!
5|this is another document
```

You could create an integer field in your standard table that refers to the FTS table by rowid, and move the columns you wish to make text-searchable into the FTS table.

All the info you need [here](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) :)